# What brand logo is this

Tags: bmx

[image]Found this bike for free. Seems to have some good stuff on it. Trying to figure out what this logo is. The seat clamp is built into the frame under the top bar if that helps.

Comment: did you try dropping the photo down to just the logo and doing a reverse image search?

Comment: I'm not to computer savvy can't figure out how to do that

Comment: Based on the gap under the chain, this might be worn out already, or at least have chain elongation.

Comment: Yea it's seem better days. It has the same logo on the frame but this was the better picture

Comment: Thanks guys.   Solved my mystery

Answer (score 2):

As per Daniel, that is definitely an Eastern Bikes logo.

[image]